# The usage of the function “getSessionMemoryStat()”

Tags: dolphindb

The usage of the function “getSessionMemoryStat()”

Can I use the function “getSessionMemoryStat()” to get the usage of the dynamic memory?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The function `getSessionMemoryStat()` detects the total memory of variables used by the current GUI; but it cannot detect the memory occupied by the function in use.